# Receiving Response CSCMATCH=Y while entering 1-digit CSC for Test Credit Card Transaction in PayPal Payflow link

Tags: paypal, payflowlink

In Setup of PayPal Manager,
I have set up in security options column,
CSC = Full
I have entered 1-digit CSC number
I am receiving CSCMATCH=Y for Test Credit Transaction in PayPal Payflow link

But,I think , transaction should be failed while entering 1-digit CSC number.
CSC number should be 3-digit or 4-digit number
Can you please explain me how to test,whether the CSC verification works fine or not?
Please guide me.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When testing, there is no check that tests to see if the CSC is 3 or 4 digits when entered.  It is simply passed over to the simulator.  So for example the value of "9" that you enter is recognized as "009".  However, once you go live the value of 9 for example would come back as a failure since it actually passes this over to the processor and card issuing bank.

If you are wanting to trigger a CSC failure, you can enter "999" for the value.  The values that you can enter to trigger specific CSC matches are listed in the developers guide.

Comment: And I have done the following set up in Security options in Paypal Manager,AVS = Full . I have entered the required details, and submit it in the Credit Card form. The test transaction is always getting failed, while AVS = full , If I set AVS= No , the transactions are successfully completed.Please guide me , How May I know , whether AVS works fine..Please guide me....

Comment: The Payflow Developer Guide also contains the values that you need to pass over for the address to trigger specific values of N, Y, or X.  These are listed in the Payflow Developers Guide under testing.